# Countdown timer don´t change textview

Tags: android, for-loop, textview, countdowntimer

In my app I am using a `CountdownTimer`. After each time the countdown timer has been executed I´m using a counter. When the counter meet a certain requirement I want the countdown timer to behave in another way `onFinish` and change the textview of my textTimer. Like it acts now my counter has already looped before starting the countdowntimer. How can I change that?

```
package org.example.anders.eazy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExerciseActivity extends Activity {

    String[] exerciseList;
    TextView textTimer,workoutTextview,exerciseTextView;
    int setsChosen;
    int counter;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        exerciseList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heavy_chest_arms);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setsChosen =intent.getExtras().getInt("setsChosen");
        String selectedWorkout = intent.getExtras().getString("workoutName");

        int timeChosen = intent.getExtras().getInt("timeChosen");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);

        for(counter=0;counter<setsChosen;counter++) {

            final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(timeChosen * 60000, 1000);
            timer.start();
            textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeUntilFinished);
            workoutTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workoutChosen);
            //exerciseTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseNow);
            //textTimer.setText("00:01:00");
            //exerciseTextView.setText(exerciseList[i]);
            workoutTextview.setText(selectedWorkout);



        }
    }
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {


        /**
         * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
         *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
         *                          is called.
         * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
         *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
         */
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis= millisUntilFinished;
            String hms=String.format("%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            textTimer.setText(hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(500);
            if(counter<setsChosen){
                this.start();
            }

            else
                textTimer.setText("Complete");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your loop and update `counter` at `onFinish()`
So, your code should be like this.

```
package org.example.anders.eazy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExerciseActivity extends Activity {

    String[] exerciseList;
    TextView textTimer,workoutTextview,exerciseTextView;
    int setsChosen;
    int counter = 0;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        exerciseList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heavy_chest_arms);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setsChosen =intent.getExtras().getInt("setsChosen");
        String selectedWorkout = intent.getExtras().getString("workoutName");

        int timeChosen = intent.getExtras().getInt("timeChosen");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);

        if (counter < setsChosen) {

            final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(timeChosen * 60000, 1000);
            timer.start();
            textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeUntilFinished);
            workoutTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workoutChosen);
            //exerciseTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseNow);
            //textTimer.setText("00:01:00");
            //exerciseTextView.setText(exerciseList[i]);
            workoutTextview.setText(selectedWorkout);



        }
    }
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {


        /**
         * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
         *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
         *                          is called.
         * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
         *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
         */
        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis= millisUntilFinished;
            String hms=String.format("%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            textTimer.setText(hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(500);
            counter ++;
            if(counter<setsChosen){
                this.start();
            }

            else
                textTimer.setText("Complete");

        }
    }
}
```

And for simply (doesn't need to create CountDownTimer's subclass). You can create a function `runCountDownTimer()` for looping like this.

```
package org.example.anders.eazy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExerciseActivity extends Activity {

    String[] exerciseList;
    TextView textTimer,workoutTextview,exerciseTextView;
    int setsChosen;
    int counter = 0;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        exerciseList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heavy_chest_arms);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setsChosen =intent.getExtras().getInt("setsChosen");
        String selectedWorkout = intent.getExtras().getString("workoutName");

        int timeChosen = intent.getExtras().getInt("timeChosen");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);

        textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeUntilFinished);
        workoutTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workoutChosen);
        //exerciseTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseNow);
        //textTimer.setText("00:01:00");
        //exerciseTextView.setText(exerciseList[i]);
        workoutTextview.setText(selectedWorkout);

        counter = 0;
        runCountDownTimer();
    }

    public void runCountDownTimer() {
        if (counter < setsChosen) {
            new CountDownTimer(timeChosen * 60000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                    System.out.println(hms);
                    textTimer.setText(hms);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    counter++;
                    runCountDownTimer();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```